# Provision Look Up column in sharepoint sandbox solution

Tags: sharepoint, sandbox, lookup

I have a sandbox solution in share point . i have created number of site columns, content types , list definitions and list instances.
Every thing has individual feature.
i mean 
1) site column feature(Site feature) 
2) site content type feature(Site feature) 
3) List destination feature(Web feature) 
4) List instance(Web feature)

i have 3 lookup columns which is provision successfully without target list.

lookup column is configure in content type and list instance.

Now, i want to update that lookup field using feature receiver and use lookup value in other list.

What should i Do?
My lookup Column element.xml is below.

```
**<Field
   ID="{a41ab4e5-a30a-4d99-8e0b-1ab2095d68f2}"
   Name="Client"
   DisplayName="Client"
   Type="Lookup"
   Required="TRUE"
   Group="Project Management System"
   List="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"
   ShowField="Title">
```

**

how can i replace list id with "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this myself, but does this blog post help? http://blog.mastykarz.nl/sharepoint-programmatically-provisioning-lookup-fields/

I don't think you're able to do this with a sandbox solution.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnE. Blog is regarding to create new field pro-grammatically. i don't want this. i want to change source ID of lookup column . But any ways, i have find the solution.